# Maximising memory when processing many HDF5 files at once in R

Tags: r, memory, try-catch, raster, hdf5

I have the code below and I need to run it on about 200,000 files. I have split the files into 10 folders and tried processing one sub folder at a time. However, the system keeps going out of memory.

```
DL3 <-lapply(DL1,fun2Fc)
```

What's the best way to run or re-write this code written below while staying within the memory limit of my PC? I had to add the "try" aspect to prevent the loop stopping if it encounters a file with no data.

```
##Run required libraries
library(rhdf5)
library(stringi)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(stringr)
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(GISTools)
library(xts)

#Define function to read in rasters for desired extent
fun2Fc<- function(x){X1<-try(h5read(x,"PIXEL_SIZE"),silent=T)
if (class(X1) == 'try-error') {
    return(NA)
}
                     LLon<-as.vector((h5read(x,"LONGITUDE"))/100)
                  LLat<-as.vector((h5read(x,"LATITUDE"))/100)
                 LFRP<-as.vector((h5read(x,"FRP"))/10)
                 LPS<-as.vector((h5read(x,"PIXEL_SIZE"))/100)
  DDD<-as.data.frame(cbind(LLon,LLat,LFRP,LPS))
  coordinates(DDD) <- ~LLon+LLat 
  proj4string(DDD) = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84")
  rast <- raster(ncol = 500, nrow = 250)
  extent(rast) <- try(c(min(LLon),max(LLon),min(LLat), max(LLat)),silent=T)
  if (min(LLon) == max(LLon)) {
    return(NA)}
  if (min(LLat) == max(LLat)) {
    return(NA)}
  DD2<-rasterize(DDD, rast, DDD$LFRP, fun = mean)
  frm<-extent(c(-19, 19,2,29))
  pfrm <- as(frm, 'SpatialPolygons')
  X1<-try(crop(DD2,pfrm),silent=T)
  if (class(X1) == 'try-error') {
    return(NA)}
  s <- raster(ncol = 76, nrow = 54,xmn=-19,xmx=19,ymn=2,ymx=29)
  proj4string(s)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84")
  R1 <- try(extend(X1,s),silent=T)
  if (class(X1) == 'try-error') {
    return(NA)}
  ###Ensure you specify the package to use for resampling as some packages clash
  R4<-raster::resample(R1, s, method="bilinear")
  R4}

DL3 <-lapply(DL1,fun2Fc)
```

Comment: Are you receiving any error or warning?

Comment: Yes, a message from the PC telling me there's no memory left. It then prompts me to clear up the memory. However, at times when I left it to run for a while, the message on the R console says something like not enough memory to complete the process or memory exceeded.